# AFNetworking results differ from CURL

Tags: rest, curl, ios6, afnetworking

I'm building a REST API with a CakePHP backend.  I'm trying to get a JSON response that I can parse using AFNetworking in iOS 6.1, but I'm getting an error when I try to hit my API URL with AFNetworking.

Here's the problematic call to AFNetworking:

```
[self postPath:@"/marks/markfav/1162" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (DEMO_LOGGING) NSLog(@"Done refreshing");
    });
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@", error.userInfo);
    });
}];
```

And here's the result with the error dump:

```
2013-06-05 00:19:35.018 ToWatchList[67945:c07] Request Failed with Error: {
    AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLRequestErrorKey = "<NSMutableURLRequest http://towatchlist.com/marks/markfav/1162>";
    AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseErrorKey = "<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x8574250>";
    NSErrorFailingURLKey = "http://towatchlist.com/marks/markfav/1162";
    NSLocalizedDescription = "Expected status code in (200-299), got 500";
    NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion = "{\"name\":\"An Internal Error Has Occurred.\",\"message\":\"\\/\"}";
}
```

I'm pretty sure the PHP backend is working correctly because I can hit it with curl and get the expected result (note I'm hitting same URL as the error above, both with POST requests):

```
$ curl -i --request POST http://towatchlist.com/marks/markfav/1162
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Jun 2013 07:21:46 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6
Set-Cookie: CAKEPHP=ijmosqrl26cao4jv8vqlt15sa6; expires=Wed, 05-Jun-2013 11:21:46 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Content-Length: 43
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"result":"0","info":"Invalid Permissions"}
```

And I have another working AFNetworking call in the same file: `[self getPath:@"/marks/data.json" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)` (It works correctly both via curl and within iOS and you can hit it with `curl -i http://towatchlist.com/marks/data.json`).

So I can't understand why I'm getting weird results for the first AFNetworking call… how do I make it behave like curl does on the command line?

PS: for background, do some basic setup by calling this function with my base URL to set up AFNetworking:

```
- (id)initWithBaseURL:(NSURL *)url
{
    self = [super initWithBaseURL:url];
    if(!self)
        return nil;
    [self registerHTTPOperationClass:[AFJSONRequestOperation class]];
    [self setDefaultHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
    [self setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    [[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Running `curl -i --request POST http://dev.towatchlist.com/marks/markfav/1162` returns `403 Forbidden` from here, so it’s going to be hard to help you diagnose your problem.

Comment: I'm aware of the forbidden status; I guess I was hoping that the issue was something I could toggle simply with AFNetworking, but obviously that's not the case otherwise it would have been answered.  I should work on updating the code so you can hit it from the public site.  I'll update the question once I've done that.  Thanks for the push in this direction.

Comment: As suggested by 0xced, I updated my post to have publicly accessible URLs so you can run `curl -i --request POST http://towatchlist.com/marks/markfav/1162` and get valid JSON back (though it will just tell you the URL is forbidden because you haven't passed in a user/pass which is expected).  Thanks for any & all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out this was a problem with a subtle difference in how PHP (or perhaps just CakePHP) handle requests from AFNetworking and CURL.

My server somehow recognized that the CURL request had no GUI or session variables and ignored that PHP code when I hit the URL with CURL.  When using AFNetworking however, it tried to execute this code (`$this->Session->setFlash($msg,'default',array('class'=>$class));
this->redirect($this->referer());`) instead of ignoring it, which caused an error.

The solution was to put the session/redirect code in a separate PHP statement that would not be executed from any post request.

Answer (score 2):

You should try with the latest version of AFNetworking. I just tested with version 1.3.0 and everything works as expected, i.e. the success block is called with `{ info = "Invalid Permissions"; result = 0; }` NSDictionary as responseObject.

Comment: Thanks for checking this out 0xced. Though it didn't turn out to be the AFNetworking version (I'm on 1.3.0 too), the fact that it worked correctly for you gave a better understanding of where the problem was and helped me figure it out.